# Azure Table Storage Session State Provider

Tags: asp.net, session, azure

Is Azure Table Storage Session Provider as an ASP.NET Session State option obsolete ?
I am not able find official Microsoft communication on this but found it in a [blog](https://codingamuseme.wordpress.com/2014/11/04/table-storage-session-provider-for-azure-is-now-obsolete-prefer-sql-server-for-session-state-as-its-easy/). Also, the links provided in this MSDN [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2013/05/17/session-state-management-in-windows-azure-web-roles/) is redirecting to home page.

I am not able to find official Microsoft communication on this.

I wish to implement it at the project level hence need to be doubly sure.
Request all to help me here please.

Comment: Have you considered using a Redis Cache instead? You want session access to be as fast as possible to minimise the performance impact and maximise scalability. You'll have the latter with table storage but not the former. Using a SQL Database is a compromise if traffic isn't an issue yet and you don't want to depend on memory and ARR.

Answer (score 2):

The Table Session State Provider is not officially supported by Microsoft and is provided as a code example to my knowledge.

I found this example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows-Azure-ASPNET-03d5dc14/sourcecode?fileId=25675&pathId=2119238232) but haven't had much more luck finding anything.

The main advantage to using table storage is cost but performance is likely to be worse so Azure Sql or Azure Redis may be better options.